# Metal Texture Formats

Tags: ios, metal

I declare a metal texture in Swift with format `.bgra8Unorm`. Now in the metal compute `kernel` I access it using the `half` data type (I believe an Apple example did it this way).

```
texture2d<half, access::sample> inTexture [[ texture(0) ]]
```

Will accessing a `bgra8Unorm` texture this way (via a sampler) and/or writing it back automatically pack and unpack `half` values to and from 8 bit integers? What happens when I write a negative `half` value to the texture?

Comment: Well, with `access::sample`, you can't write to the texture.

Comment: Yes. There is another texture param with `access::write` thats not listed here. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Yes](https://developer.apple.com/reference/metal/mtlpixelformat#overview). When writing to a texture with normalized unsigned integer components, the values are effectively clamped to [0, 1], then scaled by the maximum value of the format (255, in this case).